# Data Migration using springboot application taking too much time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, database-migration

I have created a command line application in java using springboot which migrates data from oracle database to mysql database

I am doing following in service class

```java
@Service
public class MyService{

    @Autowired
    public OracleUserRepository oracleUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OracleUserAddressRepository oracleUserAddressRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OracleUserDetailsRepository oracleUserDetailsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MysqlUserRepository mysqlUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MysqlUserAddressRepository mysqlUserAddressRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MysqlUserDetailsRepository mysqlUserDetailsRepository;

    public void migrateData(){
        List<OracleUserEntity> oracelUserEntities=oracleUserRepository.findAll();
        for (OracleUserEntiy oracleUserEntity: oracleUserEntities){
            migrateEntity(oracleUserEntity);
        }
    }

    @Transactional("mysqlTransactionManager")
    public void migrateEntity(OracleUserEntity oracleUserEntity){

        OracleUserAddressEntity oracleUserAddressEntity=getAddressEntity(oracleUserEntity);
        OracleUserDetailsEntity oracleUserDetailsEntity=getDetailsEntity(oracleDetaislEntity);


        MysqlUserEntity mysqlUserEntity=convertToMysqlUserEntity(oracleUserEntity);
        mysqlUserRepository.save(mysqlUserEntity);

        MysqlUserAddressEntity mysqlUserAddressEntity=convertToMysqlAddressEntity(oracleUserAddressEntity);
        mysqlUserAddressRepository.save(mysqlUserAddressEntity);

        MysqlUserDetailsEntity mysqlUSerDetailsEntity=convertToMysqlUserDetailsEntity(oracleUserDetailsEntity);
        mysqlUserDetailsRepository.save(mysqlUserAddressEntity);
    }
}
```

I am saving each user using **transactional** because I want to rollback if any of userAddressEntity or userDetailsEntity fails getting saved

I have around **70K** entries in oracle database. The **oracleUserRepository.findAll()** method alone took around **40 minutes** to load all entities and saving entities to mysql DB is taking even more time.

Is this the correct way to do it? Is there anyway to improve performance in this?

Comment: Is there a need to do it programmatically? Can't you use data transfer/migration tools?

Comment: You should split data and process in batch (in one transaction), and not load the whole db into memory at once.

Comment: If you can use any tool, then just export, and import. It will be way faster.

Comment: @kann the columns are different and some data has to be mapped to other values. So I have to do it programmatically

Comment: @zlaval is there any reference on how to do it in batch

Comment: 1. Use JPA batch functionality. 2. Don't use `findAll` write your own that returns a `Stream` instead. 3. There is no single transactions, in fact there are 3 s ingle ones!. 4. You have an 1+N issue, actually 1 + (2 * N) issue, as you are issuing queries to obtain the address.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does have batch functionality to improve performance.

However, this use case seems ideal for a scripting solution so that one has full control of the SQL statements and transactions.

Answer (score 0):

70K shouldn't be a problem. Try reading each row and inserting to mysql instead of finding all into memory. When you do each row approach, remove Transactional which might cause little slowness. When it fails, log exception and retry or fix the data if data issue and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be very efficient, but it should not take 40 minutes for a .findall method to load 70k records... Assuming of course your find all is simply trying to return every row, and not being overloaded with a limitation selection and the original table is huge and your select is on a non indexed column. Are you certain you are not resource bound on your Java process, or on the Oracle Server?  Is your JVM Heap big enough?

If you connect to the database with sqlplus, and run the select to find all from your User Table, how long does that take?  If that is slow as well, you have some sort of resource/contention/locking going on at the Database level... If that it responding quickly, but your program is taking 40 minutes to get the result, you need to check your JVM.. is it resource bound? etc

Comment: jvm is not resource bound but my connection to oracle database is very slow. It is taking approximately two minutes for hikari pool to add 10 connections

Comment: What is the time to run your query if you just connect to the database via SQLPLUS and run a select * from the table?  If that is slow your problem, as I stated is at the DB level... it may be contention or resource bound.